# Property 'XYZ' is missing in type CustomModel[]

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

TypeScript v2.7.2

I have the following code snippet:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Ingredient } from "../shared/ingredient.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopping-list',
  templateUrl: './shopping-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopping-list.component.css']
})
export class ShoppingListComponent implements OnInit {
  ingredients : Ingredient[] = [
    new Ingredient('Apples', 5),
    new Ingredient('Tomatoes', 10)
  ];
}
```

The "shared" folder is in the "App" folder, one step above (../ in import). I have the following in my *Ingredient* model:

```
export class Ingredient {
  constructor(public name: string, public amount: number) {}
}
```

The code definitely runs when compiled to JavaScript, but the TypeScript is stuck on an error I cannot resolve:

```
Error:(10, 3) TS2322:Type 'Ingredient[]' is not assignable to type 'Ingredient'. 
Property 'name' is missing in type 'Ingredient[]'.
```

As far as I know, I declared that I want an array type of Ingredient elements. I initiated this array with two elements, according to their corresponding types. I do understand that there is no 'Name' property in a Custom-Type-Array, but why does it expect the array to be an element, instead of, well, the array?

**Why do I get the error that the name is missing, when it is given in the constructor parameter?**

Unfortunately I cannot share the Udemy course source I was writing this from. The course material goes on without mentioning anything about it, I guess because the code compiles and runs "as expected" at this stage.

Edit: Added angular tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've placed your code into a new project I've made in angular. I've putted everything in a single file like this way:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    private ing: Ingredient[] = [
        new Ingredient('test', 10),
        new Ingredient('test', 10)
    ];
    constructor() {
        this.ing.forEach(el => {
            console.log(el);
        });
    }
}

export class Ingredient {
    constructor(public name: string, public amount: number) { }
}
```

This is working fine. I can see, in the console, the two elements of the array printed out. Can you please try to copy-pasta this code and try it ouy too? It should work without problem, I know. Actually you can try to press f12 on the "Ingredient[]" name to see if the idle you're using the right class. Also sorry for not posting it as a comment but I don't have enough reputation to do that.

Comment: I did *almost* the exact same thing and no problems on my end.

Comment: It works fine this way. It turned out NodeJS was stuck after saving some changes. A NodeJS restart would have been enough, but the IDE restart solved it. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I see one minor issue with your code, can you please try to update the following line add **'var or let'**

```
`let ingredients : Ingredient[] = [
        new Ingredient('Apples', 5),
        new Ingredient('Tomatoes', 10)
    ];`
```

I think this might help.